# Determining why an app is loading slowly

Tags: ios

I have a couple of apps that just don't have much going on, and yet they're still taking sometime 5-10 seconds to fully load. I'm somewhat new to iOS development and I'm wondering if there are obvious reasons why an app is taking so long to load.

The things I KNOW aren't the case are:

- Establishing an internet connection
- Loading many images or views

My AppDelegate is very basic, consisting of just the boilerplate code essentially. I am using Testflight, but I had this problem before that, so I don't **think** it's the problem. My initial view is a Navigation Controller with a basic ViewController in it (all made from an XIB)

I know this is kind of broad, but even just personal anecdotes could help myself and lots of future SO users, since a basic app taking > 1 second to launch is a death-sentence on the app store.

Comment: Have you tried using Instruments to profile CPU use or logging at various points to narrow it down? How big are your images or xibs?

Comment: @BergQuester The images total to ~ 800kb and the xib is smaller still.

Comment: Have you tried instruments?

Comment: @TonyD No, I haven't :) Will Instruments show things that are potentially happening in other contexts? Like behind the scenes or in an external Framework?

Comment: Yes, it has all kinds of tools you can use to monitor all the details going on in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Try profiling the application through instruments (time profiler) and see what is happening.

for more details on time profiler, refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html

Also, there are few WWDC videos that talks about time profiling in instruments.